# List of logged in users in an Express app

Tags: session, authentication, express, cookies, mongoose

I've setup basic user authentication using this http://mherman.org/blog/2015/01/31/local-authentication-with-passport-and-express-4/#.Vufc1fmLTIW

In my app I need to have a list of users who are currently logged in.
So, I decided to keep this information on user object.

```
var Account = new Schema({
     username: String,
     email: String,
     online: {type: Boolean, default: false} 
 });

 var User = mongoose.model('Account', Account);
```

When a user logs in I update **online** property on **User** object to 'true' and when she logs out to 'false':

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
        if (err) {
        return next(err); 
    }
    if (!user) {
        return res.send({ success : false, info: info.message});
    }
    req.login(user, loginErr => {
        if (loginErr) {
        return next(loginErr);
    }
    req.session.cookie.maxAge = 10 * 60 * 1000;

    var id = user['_id'];
    var update = {'$set': {'online' : 'true'}};
    var callback = function (err, data) {
        if (err) return next(err);  
    };
    Users.findByIdAndUpdate(id, update, callback);

    return res.send({ success : true});
    });      
  })(req, res, next);
 });

 router.get('/logout', function(req, res) {   
      var id = req.user['_id'];
      var update = {'$set': {'online' : 'false'}};
      var callback = function (err, data) {
           if (err) return next(err);   
      };
      Users.findByIdAndUpdate(id, update, callback);

     req.logout();
     res.redirect('/');
 });
```

Everything worsks just fine, but I need somehow to set **online** property on User object to 'false' when cookies expire. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

The only viable options I can come up with at the moment, and which I believe is quite common, is to use a timeout if no direct action to terminate the session has been called.

Based on the lifespan of your cookies, you can set a timeout on the server (setTimeout) that will invalidate the session/set online status to false if it triggers. If the user does anything before the timeout triggers, stop the timeout, and create a new one (Which is basically the same as you should be doing on your cookie).